# Изображения SVG не на правильном месте

Tags: css3, html5, svg

У меня есть SVG, который имеет черно-белое изображение.

И используя патчи с фоновыми изображениями, я хочу наложить цветные изображения поверх чёрно-белого изображения, чтобы при наведении курсора эти   части изображения превращались в цветные.

Полный код SVG можно найти [здесь](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/4dc1e574d3c0dd7ef2df0b491d8dd812)

Я присваиваю `background images`

```
<style type="text/css">
    #BosniaShape {
        fill: url(#ColorPattern); /* похоже, не работает */
    }
</style>
```

и

```
<defs>
    <pattern id="BosniaPattern" x="0" y="0" width="4800" height="2720">
        <image xlink:href="bosnia.jpg" width="281" height="319" />             
    </pattern>
</defs>
```

*base image*

```
<image xlink:href="map_bw_2560.jpg" width="4800" height="2720" id="bw" />
```

*и патч*

```
<path id="BosniaShape" class="st0" d="M1227.5,448.5c-8.99-0.4-9-3-9-6s-5-5-6-10s-1.47-10.68-7.98-11.14s-11.44,1.4-12.56,3.91
…
C1234.43,442.38,1233.27,448.76,1227.5,448.5z"/>
```

Однако [похоже](https://www.dropbox.com/s/son8d0w7j4fhvlk/Screenshot%202018-12-05%2000.07.20.png?dl=0), что изображения, не находятся в нужном месте.

`bosnia.jpg` (и другие изображения) загружаются 
Это меньшие вырезки основного изображения, но в цвете.

Изображения [Здесь](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKrq0.jpg)

Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53622801/7394871

Answer (score 2):

*Вам понадобятся только два изображения - карта серого цвета и цветная.*

Попытка иметь изображения отдельных стран просто усложняет работу.
Используйте `ColorPattern` всю цветную версию карты и применяйте ее для всех форм страны.

Вы не указали полный путь для своих стран, поэтому в следующем примере я просто использовал квадраты заполнителей.

Чтобы увидеть результат,- наведите мышку на прямоугольники

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="map" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 4800 2720">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{
        stroke:#000000; /* so you can see them */
        stroke-width: 3px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        opacity: 0.4;
        fill: url(#ColorPattern);
    }
    path:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>
<defs>
    <pattern id="ColorPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
             x="0" y="0" width="4800" height="2720">
        <image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/cPCnxHa.jpg" width="4800" height="2720" />           
    </pattern>
</defs>

<image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/A0PPmdT.jpg" width="4800" height="2720" id="bw" />

<path id="SyriaContestedShape" class="st0" d="M400,400 h800 v800 h-800 Z"/>
<path id="YugoslaviaShape" class="st0" d="M2000,400 h800 v800 h-800 Z"/>
<path id="SyriaShape" class="st0" d="M3600,400 h800 v800 h-800 Z"/>
<path id="TurkeyShape" class="st0" d="M1200,1600 h800 v800 h-800 Z"/>
<path id="BosniaShape" class="st0" d="M2800,1600 h800 v800 h-800 Z"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Работает на планшете ....